# Is there a way to get the declared value of constraint in hibernate validator in another class?

Tags: java, reflection, hibernate-validator

Using the hibernate validator i declare something like this

```
public class TestSomething{

    @Length(max=30, message="Error Message.")
    private String name;

    getter and setter here
 }
```

is it possible to get the maximum number of character in this case 30
something like

```
   TestSomething ts = new TestSomething();
   int maxValue =  ts.getName.getThatMaximumNumberOrSomethng
```

will java reflection on this kind of situation?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Bean Validation metadata API. Provided you have a `Validator` instance you can get hold of a so called `ConstraintDescriptor`:

```
BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = getBeanDescriptor( TestSomething.class );
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = beanDescriptor.getConstraintsForProperty( "name" );
Set<ConstraintDescriptor<?>> constraintDescriptors = propertyDescriptor.getConstraintDescriptors();
```

Once you have the right `ConstraintDescriptor` you can either call

```
constraintDescriptor.getAnnotation(); // to get the actual constraint annotation
constraintDescriptor.getAttributes().get("max"); // to retrieve the attribute from the attributes map provided by the descriptor as convenience
```